# When to use E[a X] = a E[X] (Expectation Property)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The Question is:

If X(t) = Asin(ωt+θ) where θ and ω are constants and A is a uniformly distributed random variable in (0,1). Calculate ensemble mean and correlation and comment on its stationarity.

Is it right if I find mean as following?

> **E[** X(t) **]** = **E[** A sin(ωt+θ) **]** = sin(ωt+θ) **E[** A **]**

P.S.
When to use this property of expectation and when not to?

Comment: What you have done is fine. $E[aX] = a E[X]$ always holds (provided $a$ is a deterministic/non-random quantity).

Comment: Thanks for answering.
What if θ were not a constant, in that case what could we say about sin(ωt+θ), random or deterministic? We could still predict it.

Comment: Without additional hypotheses over $\theta$, the latter would be a random variable and so would $\sin( \omega t + \theta)$ be. Thus, no transformation possible.

Answer (score 1):

In general, as pointed by @angryavian in the comment section, for a non-random $a$ we have $$E[aX]=aE[X]$$

You also have that the following result holds if $a$ is independent of $X$ (note that this generalizes the previous statement as a non-random $a$ is always independent of $X$)

$$E[aX]=E[a]E[X]$$

Comment: I'd mention the less restrictive non-correlated variables too. Plus, the phrase lacks the expected value notion for $a$. :)

Comment: You are right! Fixed it, thanks